# Find intervals decrease and increase of a function $f(x)=\frac{\pi x}{2}-x\arctan x$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives

Find intervals decrease and increase of a function.

$f(x)=\frac{\pi x}{2}-x\arctan x$

$f'(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan x-\frac{x}{1+x^2}$

$f''(x)=\frac{-2}{(1+x^2)^2}$

which is negative. What can I say from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as $f''(x)<0$ so $f'$ is decreasing $$f'(x)> \lim_{x\to \infty} f'(x)=\pi/2-\pi/2=0$$ so $f'(x)$ is alsways $>0$

Comment: Sorry for silly question but why you are considering only $x \to \infty$?

Comment: @VardanDanielyan as $f'$ is decreasing it would achieve its minimum when x is maximum .It would be meaningless to write $f'(\infty)$

Answer (score 0):

Interval for which $f$ increases: $(-∞, ∞)$. Interval which $f$ decreases: none

$f$ is strictly increasing, concave downward and   $f(x)\to1$  as $x\to\infty$

---

Background information.

Since $f'(x)> 0$, $f''(x) < 0$, we conclude that $f$ is strictly increasing and concave downward.

interval of increasing for $f: (-∞, ∞)$, interval of decreasing for $f$: none

As $x\to\infty$ we have

$$f(x) = 1 - \frac1{3 x^2} + \frac1{5 x^4} - \frac1{7 x^6} + O\left(x^{-7}\right).$$

Hence $\lim\nolimits_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 1$.

Comment: Please have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation and re-fromat you answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok, Gary.  It'll take me some time to reformat as I'm not familiar with Mathjax/Latex symbol.

Comment: Ok, Gary. It's done. Please take a look to see if it conforms to the community requirements.

Comment: I added some further edits.